# Calling child attributes before super()?

Tags: java

I work primarily with dynamic languages - I've just started playing with Java, and I'm struggling with a static pattern.

From what I understand, the first call in the constructor of a child class has to be to its parent. That's fine, but I need to set instance variables in the child that are referenced in the constructor of the parent...which, of course, creates a catch-22. (Need to set variables in child before calling parent, but need to call parent before setting variables in child).

I'm sure I'm breaking some sort of static language pattern or law...I'm just not sure which one, or how to redesign it. Any help appreciated. Stripped down example below:

```
Class Race {

  public Race(Venue event_venue) {
    greeting();
  }

  public void greeting() {
    String event_greeting = String.format("The next event is: %s", getName());
    System.out.println(event_greeting);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }
}

Class Sprint extends Race {
  private int event_distance;

  public Sprint(Venue event_venue, int distance) {
    // super has to be the first call
    super(event_venue);
    // but I need to set event_distance to reference getName() in parent constructor
    setDistance(distance);
  }

  public String getName() {
    String sprint_name = String.format("%s meter sprint", Integer.toString(getDistance());
    return sprint_name;
  }

  public int getDistance() {
    return distance;
  }

  public void setDistance(int distance) {
    event_distance = distance;
  }
}
```

Comment: *That's fine, but I need to set instance variables in the child that are referenced in the constructor of the parent* Bad design ,your parent shouldn't know about child.

Comment: You mean you want `Sprint#getName()` to be called when you create a new Sprint object, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot, does that mean OPs problem cannot get solved?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot what are abstract methods for if not "future knowing" about children?

Comment: @m0skit0 I was talking about attributes , not abstract methods per se !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Attributes can be set through abstract methods :P

Comment: @m0skit0 But how can the non abstract parent exist , like in OP's case without knowing its attributes and depending on the sub class for the construction of its objects !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot You're right, that's a bad design. Parent class should be abstract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have side-effects in your constructor, which is frowned upon. For best results, put the side-effects in an other method. You have this already, so just specify in the javadoc that `greeting()` should be called after construction (or, it could be called by the subclass constructors, but then sub-subclasses will have the same problem).

Answer (score 1):

I assume each race will have a distance, so why not make this field part of the supertype.  This field can then be set via an argument provided to the constructor.

```
Class Race {
  private int event_distance;
  public Race(Venue event_venue, int distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
    greeting();
  }

  public void greeting() {
    String event_greeting = String.format("The next event is: %s", getName());
    System.out.println(event_greeting);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  public int getDistance() {
    return distance;
  }

  public void setDistance(int distance) {
    event_distance = distance;
  }
}
```

Providing `distance` as argument to super constructor:

```
Class Sprint extends Race {
  private int event_distance;

  public Child(Venue event_venue, int distance) {
    super(event_venue, distance);
  }
  /* omitted rest of class */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that does not work.

You need to refactor your code in ways that make it possible to execute the constructors in their proper order. Usually this is not a problem if the constructors do not have side-effects and do not call methods that can be overridden in subclasses (both of which are discouraged patterns).

```
public Race(Venue event_venue) {
  greeting();   // constructor should not call non-final method
}

// method called by a constructor should not print anything
public void greeting() {
   String event_greeting = String.format("The next event is: %s", getName());
   System.out.println(event_greeting);
}
```